# Azure Connection String Failing

Tags: azure, connection-string

I have a dev system connecting to an Azure database.  Works fine.  When I deploy the system to an Azure WebApp, I get sql connection error "The server was not found or was not accessible."

Some more information:
In App Services > GreenStore > Settings > Application Settings I have filled in the connection strings as follows:

```
    DefaultConnection Server=tcp:gserver.database.windows.net,1433;
    Data Source=gserver.database.windows.net;
    Initial Catalog=GDB;Persist Security Info=False;
    User ID=xxx@xxxxserver;Password=xxxxxxx;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=10 
    SQL Server

    StoreDBEntities
    metadata=res://*/Models.StoreModels.csdl|res://*/Models.StoreModels.ssdl|res://*/Models.StoreModels.msl;
    Server=tcp:gserver.database.windows.net,1433;
    Data Source="gserver.database.windows.net;
    Initial Catalog=GDB;Persist Security Info=False;
    User ID=xxx@xxxxserver;Password=xxxxxxx;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=10;"
    Custom
```

Is there a mistake in the connection strings which I entered in App Services > GreenStore > Settings > Application Settings or is another issue.  I can connect from my dev machine using the above connections strings in web.config versions.

Comment: Did you set up the SQL Database firewall to allow access from other Azure services?

Comment: To elaborate on the above statement. Ensure that the Public IP address of your location (or locations) is added as a firewall rule on the SQL server

Comment: Yes. Settings > Firewall setting > Allow access to Azure Services = On.

Comment: Please note - I can connect from my dev machine through the fire wall with my IPs added.  But when I publish, and try to connect to the hosted webApp - I get the error. I assume that for the hosted webApp I don't need to add IPs - correct?

Comment: Note - I can connect with SSMS